# Where do I put the REST Client Authentication Data in the Query?

Tags: java, android, http, rest, restful-authentication

I need to work with REST api in android application which is created by my client. Below text is just copied from the pdf the client provides us.

--
In this example, a new user is created.
The parts of a possible request to the server is shown below:

Message part Contents

```
Header POST {url-prefix}/rest/user
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 205
Body <request>
  <client>
    <id>XY</id>
    <name>myName</name>
    <password>myPassword</password>
  </client>
  <user>
    <name>myUserName</name>
    <password>myUserPassword</password>
    <groupId>12345</groupId>
  </user>
</request>
```

--
After searching and studying, I come to know that, the possible request code (in Java) might be:

```
URL url=new URL("http://api.example.com/rest/user/?name=myUserName&password=myUserPassword&groupId=12345");
            HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("Post");
            OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write("respose content:");
            out.close();
```

From the pdf manual they provide, I got to know, *for every request to the server, the client (thats me) has to transmit  the authentication data.*
**My question is, where do I put the authentication data in the query string? Please help me on this.**

Edit:After posting the below code as request:

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api.example.com/rest/user/?name=Foysal&password=123456&groupid=12345");
            httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "APIappDevAccount"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123456"));           
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
            httpClient.setParams(params);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf;
            int ByteRead;
            buf = new byte[1024];
            String xmldata = null;
            double totalSize = 0;
            while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
                os.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
                totalSize += ByteRead;                      
            }
            xmldata =  os.toString();
            os.close();
            is.close();
```

But I got the response as:

> 404
>   Not Found
>
> ## Not Found
>
> The requested
>   URL /rest/user/ was not found on this
>   server.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.2.6
>   (Fedora) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.6
>   OpenSSL/0.9.8b Server at 
>   api.example.com Port 80

Comment: When you get a "404 Not Found", that means you got the wrong URL. If you would have an authentication problem, "401 Unauthorized" would be the appropriate status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like they want you to POST an XML document and put the authentication in that. Not much of a REST API (most REST APIS don't require an XML document).

You need to use conn.getOutputStream() to send that doc to the server and use conn.getInputStream() to read the response.

So you would have to create the XML doc like the one they show:

```
<request>
  <client>
    <id>XY</id>
    <name>myName</name>
    <password>myPassword</password>
  </client>
  <user>
    <name>myUserName</name>
    <password>myUserPassword</password>
    <groupId>12345</groupId>
  </user>
</request>
```

And then send it in your POST:

```
conn.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "text/xml" );
out.write(requestDoc); //where requestDoc is the String containing the XML.
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: POST or better PUT some XML to create a new user seems RESTful to me. What's wrong about that?

Comment: @TimButhe: Not sure I missed the point, the way I read it is they want the authentication in the xml doc itself. See how it has a client and user section? I think they want the authentication there in the client section.

Comment: @TimButhe: As for it being RESTful or not, from a strict definition of REST you are probably correct. But in common usage (Facebook Legacy REST API or newer Graph API would be examples), a simple GET request is used. Others might use POST but would use simple name=value pairing like a web form. So basically get away from the overhead of using XML for everything.

Comment: maybe Foysal can clear that up for us. I thought the request should create a new user, since he wrote "_In this example, a new user is created_". Well, let's see.

Comment: Yup, he'll need to clarify, but we are both in agreement that he is trying to create a new user with that request. No confusion there. See how it has 2 sections a client and user section? Client section is for his username/password that he's established with the server for doing requests. User section is to create a new user on their service (whatever that is). That's my interpretation.

Comment: There are also some functionality I want to do but the basic scenario is stated in the question.

Comment: @Fraggle: What do I do if i want to perform the other REST operations something like: Get, Put, Delete etc? should I change  'conn.setRequestMethod("Post");' code to 'conn.setRequestMethod("Delete");' if i want to perform the delete operation?

Comment: please tell me how do i get the response from the code you given.

Answer (score 0):

You may execute a POST request like shown here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient and put the authentication data as name value pairs:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "myUserName"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "myUserPassword"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // ... handle exception here
}
```

Comment: I am using Java. Could you please change the HttpPost url for me?

Comment: Well, that's just an example, just change it in your implementation.

Comment: so if i use this way, i would have to replace the HttpPost class with HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpPut classes. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The HttpClient classes are actually from the Apache http components project and were integrated into android. You can find the documentation at http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: is there any way to send multiple tag's value in a single query string? in my case, is it possible to send client's and user's value at single string?

Comment: If you don't want to use "UrlEncodedFormEntity", there are other Entities, like StringEntity that will let you construct the content yourself. See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/AbstractHttpEntity.html

Comment: Stop the madness ! If you want to end up with an XML doc like the one posted in the question, then you won't get that using nameValuePairs. You have to post the XML doc. Does the receiver of this post expect an XML doc or a standard name/value pairs http POST?